# Using Multiprocessing on a Collection of DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concurrency, multiprocessing

### Setup

I have a multiple datasets each with their own `DataFrame`. I'm running calculations within them before comparing my results to a separate `DataFrame` which we can think of as constraints.

For example lets say 2 sets of data in a dictionary:

```py
df_data_1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,50,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df_data_2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,50,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
    
data_sets = {'data_1': df_data, 'data_2': df_data_2}
```

and one set of constraints:

```py
df_constraints = pd.DataFrame([['a', 10, 20, 10000000], 
                               ['b', 100, 200, 20000000], 
                               ['c', 1000, 2000, 30000000]])
df_constraints.columns = ['index', 'sumMin', 'sumMax', 'productMax']
df_constraints.set_index('index', inplace=True)
```

Visually:
[data_set_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jklfy.png)
[data_set_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJOBi.png)
[constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYDFn.png)

### Function

I'm making calculations within each set of data and then comparing them to a set of constraints. For the sake of simplifying my question I am only comparing the data to the first row of constraints here, but in reality I have to compare the results of my calculations within each data-set to up to 20 sets of constraints.

Here is a simplified version of the function that I am trying to have run in parallel:

```py
def test_func(df_data, df_constraints):
    # Run some calculations
    df = df_data.copy()
    df['sum'] = df.sum(axis=1)
    df['product'] = df.product(axis=1)
    
    # Compare results to constraints
    df['sumFit'] = ((df['sum'] > df_constraints.loc['a', 'sumMin']) &
                    (df['sum'] < df_constraints.loc['a', 'sumMax'])) 
    df['productFit'] = df['product'] < df_constraints.loc['a', 'productMax']
        
    # Analyze results
    count_sumFits = df['sumFit'].sum()
    count_productFits = df['productFit'].sum()
    
    df_results = pd.DataFrame([['data_set_1', count_sumFits, count_productFits]], 
                                columns=['DataSet', 'FittingSums', 'FittingProducts'])
    df_results.set_index('DataSet', inplace=True)
    
    return df_results
```

### Sequential Version

I can run this function sequentially through each set of data; iterating through the dictionary with a while loop and then append the results as shown here, but with increased complexity this is taking way longer than I would like. (It's ugly but it works)

```py
n=0
while n < len(data_sets):
    data_set_names = list(data_sets.keys())
    df_temp = test_func(data_sets[data_set_names[n]], df_constraints)
    
    df_all_results.loc[n, 'FittingSums']     = df_temp.loc[0, 'FittingSums']
    df_all_results.loc[n, 'FittingProducts'] = df_temp.loc[0, 'FittingProducts']
    n+=1
```

### The Problem

When I have 25 data-sets and I'm running more complex analysis with more calculations, the run time ends up being minutes long. Leading me to pursue concurrency/multiprocessing. I'm hoping to make this significantly faster as it is one step of many that I'm trying to optimize and then run them all a few thousand times.

### So, Multiprocessing...

Due to the need to pass two arguments to the function I've been looking at `mp.Pool.starmap`, and `pool.map(partial(test_func, b=df_constraints), data_sets`, but I haven't been able to get either method to work.

#### ex.1) `mp.Pool.starmap`

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool(processes = 8)
    output = pool.starmap(test_file.test_func, zip(data_sets, itertools.repeat(df_contraints)
```

This is as far as I've been able to get. Is it possible to process data concurrently like this and then append results to a dataframe? I don't need them to be in any particular order I just want to get the data into the right format.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your code and your logic but replace `data_sets` by `data_sets.values()`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool(processes = 8)
    output = pool.starmap(test_file.test_func, zip(data_sets.values(),itertools.repeat(df_contraints)))
```

Comment: Thanks, I made that change, but it's still not working

Comment: What errors do you have? Update your question.

Comment: I've gotten a few different ones but the best/worst scenario I have and what lead to the post was that I wouldn't get any output and it just sits in an infinite loop of processing. When I get back to my system I'll update my question with the error if I can get one.

Comment: I'm beginning to think that the issue is related to sharing memory and am exploring using `mp.manager.Namespace()` as a way to access the dataframes; however I'm still running into issues with getting what the function is returning to actually be returned.